# width of container / width of div does not occupy the entire width of the page even when changing to different screen resolutions

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I have my App in React.js:

```
<header className="header__section">
    
</header>
```

Here is my CSS file (SCSS):

```
.header__section {
    width: 120rem; 
    height: 48rem;
    background-image: url("../Assets/someimage.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;

}
```

I tried adding the following to my CSS (SCSS) file:

I also tried adding:

```
body, html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

/** but it did not fix it as well */

The problem is that the header__section's width does not occupy the entire width of the page, instead, there is a white area on the right, for some reason the header does not stretch to the entire width of the screen, even when changing to different screen resolutions.

Here is a screenshot of the header__section:

[image: header__section]

What is a possible fix to the above ?

Comment: Width we normally specify using %, kindly try that way. Use `width:80%;` instead of `width: 80rem;`

Comment: The way you've set up the SCSS, you've explicitly set a width and height on `.header_section` - no matter what you do on the `html` or `body` elements, anything on the `.header_section` will override it unless you use the '!important` flag on the `html` or `body` elements. If making the relevant tweaks to prevent that clash doesn't solve the issue, then you'll need to look at maybe repeating the background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to set the width of .header__section to 100% rather than 80rem

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 The question is "What is a fix to make the header stretch the entire width?", and I think this suggested change answers the question pretty well. If they were to ask "Why is it not possible to use `width: 100%` in this case?", I would agree with you.

Comment: @abc_123 one quick question, the position relative + top and left attributes. Are you using these to position the background image? If so remove them completely and use the background-position attribute instead https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: hmm, could you try changing html, body to {width: 100%} instead of min-width: fit-content;

Comment: As this is a react project, is everything contained inside a #root element? if so you may want to set width to 100% on that as well, just in case it default sizing has been altered somehow